# Find Area of trapezium with circle inside

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

There is an exercise:

---

[image]

---

so how to solve it?

Comment: Probably better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com as this is not exactly a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10AB/2+10BC/2+10CD/2+10DA/2=
5(AB+CD)+5(BC+DA)=
240 + 5(BC+DA) = 
240 + 5(AB+CD)=
480
```